# Can't find .bin file generated by app inside docker container

Tags: c#, docker, mono, nancy, dokku

I have a c#/mono app running inside a docker container, using the very cool Dokku.

The app allows for token authentication and saves the keys used to validate incoming tokens inside the folder `/keyChain/keyChain.bin` in the root folder of the app. The app generates this folder and file by itself when it soes not exists, usually after a fresh deploy and the first auth requests comes in.

I need to mount the `keyChain` folder as a docker volume so the keychain gets persisted between deploys and not all users sessions are expired, forcing all users to sign in again.

However, although the app runs fine and auth works, the `keyChain` folder and it's contents are nowhere to be found inside the app folder, inside the Docker container, so there is nothing to mount...

Running `dokku run app-name ls /app` shows the contents of the app but not the `keyChain` folder. Running `dokku run app-name find /app -type f -name "keyChain.bin"` to just look for the file that way yields no results either.

I am using the NancyFx framework for the app with the Nancy.Authentication.Token package.

I am not fully sure if this is a docker/dokku related issue, a c#/mono issue or NancyFx/Nancy.Authentication.Token issue. Remember, the apps WORKS, so the `keyChain.bin` file must be inside the container somewhere...

Any insight is appreciated :-).

Comment: Maybe try to log full path to keychain folder\file from application itself (on startup?) and see what it shows.

Comment: I ended up rewriting a bit of code to save the keychain to the database instead of a file on disk. The keychain is loaded only once from the db during app start so there is no penalty on each request. Works better with my backup strategy as well.